# Crazy behavior (at least to me) when setting one string to another in Ruby

Tags: ruby

As a novice it's probably something about Ruby I missed, but for the life of me I don't understand this result. So I have this simple function:

```
def crazyfunc(s)
  s.gsub!('a', 'b')
  #return has not purpose here
end
```

Now I have this simple few sets.

```
s1 = 'abc'
s2 = s1
s2 = crazyfunc(str2)

puts s1

=> bbc
```

Why in the world is s1 affected by crazyfunc? So doing this instead:

```
def crazyfunc(s)
  return s.gsub('a', 'b')
end
```

doesn't change str1, so I figure it's got to do with what the inplace gsub is doing. But I still don't get the logic of why str1 would be changed.

Comment: i edited `return strin` to be `return string`

Comment: wait, never call an attribute on a column 'string'

Comment: ok, so I changed all the 'string' variables. String is fundamentally a reserved word. Never use this as a variable.

Comment: uhh, i wasn't calling a column string, i was calling it strin. you changed that :) granted, i didn't need the `return strin` since Ruby implicitly returns from def - i see that now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String assignment in Ruby doesn't implicitly copy the string. You are simply assigning another reference to it. If you want to copy the string, use clone.

To demonstrate, you can check object IDs:

```
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > a = "foo"
 => "foo"
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > b = a
 => "foo"
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > a.object_id
 => 81728090
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > b.object_id
 => 81728090
```

Since `a` and `b` have the same object ID, you know they're the same object. If you want to modify `b` as a copy of `a`, you can either use methods which return a new string (like `gsub` rather than `gsub!`), or you can use `b = a.clone`, and then operate on `b`.

```
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > a = "foo"
 => "foo"
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > b = a.clone
 => "foo"
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > a.object_id
 => 81703030
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > b.object_id
 => 81696040
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > b.gsub! "f", "e"
 => "eoo"
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > a
 => "foo"
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > b
 => "eoo"
```

Or more simply:

```
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > a = "foo"
 => "foo"
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > b = a.gsub("f", "e")
 => "eoo"
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > puts a, b
foo
eoo
```

Comment: Shoot, dang that's clear/obvious. Not thinking to clearly at 2 in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into the fact that everything in Ruby is an object, and that variables are just object references.

When you assign str1 = to str2, you are actually pointing them at the same object. When you then change the object pointed to by str2, you are also changing the object pointed to by str1.

In your original crazyfunc, you modify the string, return the modified string, and then change the value of the object pointed to by str2 - and str1, since they point to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

```
s1 = 'abc'
s2 = s1
s2 = crazyfunc(str2)
```

A  `#master`

B = A

C = B

A is A, and B equals A and C equals B. If you change B it doesn't affect A but affects C. See how it cascades down. The variables you list are just pointers.

So you only have 1 master variable here and you need to declare two.